# Quantum Simulation of Hamiltonian $H=Z_1 \otimes Z_2 \otimes Z_3$ (Nielsen 4.7.3)

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-computer

In section 4.7.3 of the Nielsen & Chuang they are talking about a quantum simulation of the Hamiltonian

\begin{equation}
H=Z_1 \otimes Z_2 \otimes Z_3
\end{equation}

on 3 qbits.

They propose this circuit

[image]

And my question is: if the operation $e^{-i\Delta t Z}$ is available, why don't you just apply it to each qbit and be done with it like this

[image]

it involves less operations and is much more straightforward.

Answer (score 3):

The circuit you give simulates $H'=Z_1+Z_2+Z_3$, not $H=Z_1\otimes Z_2\otimes Z_3$.

---

*Hint:* $H'$ has eigenvalues $\pm3,\pm1$, while $H$ has eigenvalues $\pm1$.  What are the eigenvalues of the two circuits you give? In particular, how many distinct eigenvalues are there? (Note that the CNOTs don't change the spectrum, as the spectrum of $UVU^\dagger$ is the same as the spectrum of $V$.)

Comment: Great Answer! Could you elaborate a bit more on these two hamiltonians? What does the evolution operator look like in each case? What do they represent physically? Both look like rotating each spin in the Z direction. Thanks!

Comment: @P.C.Spaniel Why don't *you* first elaborate on what your thoughts are on the evolution operator in these two cases?  Otherwise it looks like you want us to do your homework for you.